# Mapbox, cannot setGeoJSON in jquery callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mapbox

I want through Jquery retrieve some geojson points data (i.e. set some markers in a map) from a database. The

```
function remm(id){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"geojson2.php",
    data:{
        u_id:id[0],
        t_id:id[2]
    },
    success: function(geo,status){
        myLayer.setGeoJSON([geo]);
        console.log(geo);
    }
  });
}
```

When testing the points data retrieved from geojson2.php in GeoJSON Lint it works perfectly well. However, when calling the myLayer.setGeoJSON() function it only takes all existing markers away. myLayer is instantiated at the beginning of the javascript file and looks like:

```
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'key';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([40, 0], 1);
    var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
```

Since it takes away all markers from the map it doesn't seem to be that myLayer is not available to the callback function in the ajax. What could be the issue and what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `.setGeoJSON` method replaces GeoJSON - it's setting GeoJSON, not adding individual features. If you'd like to add new features instead of replacing your existing content, I'd recommend creating a new layer for the features you're loading with `jQuery`, with the `L.mapbox.featureLayer` method, and adding it to the map.

Comment: I've tried that but that doesn't work either. Is the instantiated 'map' and 'myLayer' objects global so that all functions, no matter where you have it in the script (regular js functions, jquery callbacks, etc.)? @tmcw

Comment: > Is the instantiated 'map' and 'myLayer' objects global so that all functions, no matter where you have it in the script

That's entirely dependent on where you instantiate them. If you create them with `var` and instantiate them outside of any function or closure, then yes, they're global.

Comment: They are only instantiated directly inside the script with var so I guess they become global in that case. Thanks! @tmcw